# How to create parse database for simple listing application in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, list, parse-platform

I would like to create database in parse.com for simple application.
where I will have four cells in first view 
 if I click on any cell, it will go to the next screen and contains some more cells. it goes on like that .

Problem is I have never worked with parse database creation .
can some one help...

Answer (score 2):

database creation is very easy using parse.com. A table is termed as an object in parse. To create a table/object use

```
PFObject *gameScore = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
gameScore[@"score"] = @1337;  
gameScore[@"playerName"] = @"Sean Plott";
gameScore[@"cheatMode"] = @NO;
[gameScore saveInBackground];
```

As this code executes from your Ios app you will see a table "GameScore" with attributes "score", "playerName" and "cheatMode" on your parse data browser.
In the same way you can create different tables.
You can also create a primary(unique) key for each of your table and can link them using those keys.

[ios parse.com](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects/iOS)

Comment: Thanks test   .. Can we create class and insert data , then can we fetch in the application.. I mean without using PFObject..

Comment: to insert data in a object you have to use the PFObject otherwise how you are gonna point to your object/table at parse database. So to save data from your ios app use the same code that i have wriiten in my answer. To fetch the data from parse database you have to use PFQuery. Parse has a very easy and detailed documetaion. just go through it(mentioned the link in the ans.).

Comment: If you're unhappy with using PFObject directly, you can subclass it for your model classes: https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#subclasses/iOS

Answer (score -2):

Try this Appcoda tutorials

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-app-backend-parse/

and also check parse official site as well

https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS